# I use this on palindrome question on leetcode and it still says output of 10 is true

Tags: java, palindrome

The question asked on leetcode is: Given an integer x, return true if x is palindrome integer.

An integer is a palindrome when it reads the same backward as forward. For example, 121 is palindrome while 123 is not.

This is my code.

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(int x) {
        if (x <= 9) { 
            //negative numbers are not palindromes
            if (x < 0)  {
               return false;
            } 
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
        //if anything is divisible by 10 with no remainders its not a palindrome
        if (x % 10 ==0) {
            return false;
        }
            
        //creating reverse method
        int reverse = 0;
    
        while(x > reverse) {
             int num = x % 10;
             x /= 10;
             reverse = (reverse * 10) + num;
        }
        if (x == reverse || x == reverse / 10) {
             return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm quite sure my logic is correct but I test on NetBeans with no seen errors and receive 121 being a correct answer but 10 is showing up as true when it should be false due to not being a palindrome? I'm confused and would like some help with understanding the logic a little better.

Comment: Well, your code says to do something if `x <= 9`, and otherwise `return true;` because you wrote an `else` block after that. So your code returns `true` because 10 is not less than or equal to 9.

Comment: A more straightforward solution would be to convert to a string, reverse the string and check if the reversed string and original match.

Comment: well 01 is technically 1 and in your second condition you are checking 01== (10/10), where 10/10 is again 1 so your logic is not valid on that statement, since the statement is 1==1 which is true

Comment: the question asks me not to convert to string.

Comment: @PPProgrammer you will have to change your if statement

Comment: 0 is an integer and is a palindrome so `if (x % 10 ==0) { return false; }` seems suspect.

Comment: @Andy just saw the complete code I believe the first if statement itself is in fault as 10<=9 is false and returns true that is the same thing happening in 121<=9 so according to the program anything <=9 is true he needs to fix that first

Comment: i have changed an if statement and it is now reading 10 as false but it is still reading numbers such as 133 as true why is this the case?

Comment: i have just checked your feedback and gotten rid of the first if statement as it was redundant because of the while loop logic. thank you for all your feedback!

Comment: See here: [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: `return String.valueOf(intValue).equalsIgnoreCase(new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(intValue)).reverse().toString());`

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve the same thing by:

1. Decomposing your number into digits. You can use `ArrayList`.
2. Comparing every `i`th element with the `n-i`th

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static boolean palindrome(int number)
    {
        if (number < 0)
            number *= -1; // Or return false if you want to exclude negative numbers
        
        // 1. Decompose the number into digits
        ArrayList<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (number > 0) {
            digits.add(number % 10);
            number /= 10;
        }
        
        // 2. Check
        for (int i = 0, j = digits.size()-1; i < j; i++, j--) {
            if (digits.get(i) != digits.get(j))
                return false;
        }
        
        return true;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(palindrome(121));
        System.out.println(palindrome(123));
        System.out.println(palindrome(10));
    }
}
```

Output:

```text
true
false
false
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the first check - you always return true for any number bigger than 9.

This:

```
        if (x <= 9) { 
            //negative numbers are not palindromes
            if (x < 0)  {
               return false;
            } 
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
```

Should've been this:

```
        if (x <= 9) { 
            //negative numbers are not palindromes
            if (x < 0)  {
               return false;
            } 
            else {
              return true;
            }
        }
```

And even this is way too verbose. Simpler way to write same logic is

```
        if (x <= 9) { 
            //negative numbers are not palindromes, but positive single digit numbers are
            return x >= 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(x==0){
      return true;
  }
  if(x<0 || x%10 ==0){
      return false;
  }
```

Change first two if connections with my codes. Gonna work it.